# Calculating the number of Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: php, date

How can I calculate the number of Saturdays and Sundays between two dates in php?

Is there any inbuilt function for that purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate business days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a related question here already, [Calculate business days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days)

You can use this to subtract from 7 to get the weekend days, or similar.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a built in for that, but this should do the job :

```
$startTime = START_TIMESTAMP;
$endTime = END_TIMESTAMP;
$time = $startTime;
$count = 0;

while(date('w', $time) != 0) { // 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
    $time += 86400;
}

while($time < $endTime) {
    $count++;
    $time += 7 * 86400;
}
```

Comment: what if timestamp in startdate comes saturday

Comment: It works too, `date('w', $time) == 0` so you go to the second while and `$count++`, you have one saturday at least.

Comment: Instead of `while(date('w', $time) != 0)` you can just do `$time = strtotime("Saturday")` or `$time = strtotime("Sunday")`.

Answer (score 2):

Let us all KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid). Why make it so complicated?

```
function countWeekendDays($start, $end)
{
    // $start in timestamp
        // $end in timestamp


    $iter = 24*60*60; // whole day in seconds
    $count = 0; // keep a count of Sats & Suns

    for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i=$i+$iter)
    {
        if(Date('D',$i) == 'Sat' || Date('D',$i) == 'Sun')
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate it mathematically like this  - [Based on Roland's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44942039/642706)

```
private function getNumberOfWeekendDays(\DateTimeInterface $startDate, \DateTimeInterface $endDate): int
{
    $startNumber = (int) $startDate->format('N');
    $endNumber = (int) $endDate->format('N');
    $daysBetweenStartAndEnd = $endDate->diff($startDate)->d;

    $weekendDays = (int) (2 * ($daysBetweenStartAndEnd + $startNumber) / 7);
    $weekendDays = $weekendDays - ($startNumber == 7 ? 1 : 0) - ($endNumber == 7 ?  1 :  0);

    return $weekendDays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
$d1 = new DateTime("2009-06-01"); /* inclusive */
$d2 = new DateTime("2009-07-01"); /* exclusive */

$interval = $d2->diff($d1);
$number_of_days = $interval->format("%d");

$number_of_weekends = $number_of_days / 7;
$remainder = $number_of_days % 7;

if ($remainder >=2 && $d1->format("D") == "Sat")
    $number_of_weekends++;
elseif ($d1->format("w") + $remainder >= 8)
    $number_of_weekends++;
```

I may have missed by one in the last condition, be sure to check it with different starting dates. (Feel free to edit this answer if you spot an error).

Answer (score 0):

there's definitely no built in function for that but you can use strtotime to loop days

```
$start = strtotime('2010-01-01');
$end = strtotime('2010-01-09');

function numWeekdays( $start_ts, $end_ts, $day, $include_start_end = false ) {

    $day = strtolower( $day );
    $current_ts = $start_ts;
    // loop next $day until timestamp past $end_ts
    while( $current_ts < $end_ts ) {

        if( ( $current_ts = strtotime( 'next '.$day, $current_ts ) ) < $end_ts) {
            $days++;
        }
    }

    // include start/end days
    if ( $include_start_end ) {
        if ( strtolower( date( 'l', $start_ts ) ) == $day ) {
            $days++;
        }
        if ( strtolower( date( 'l', $end_ts ) ) == $day ) {
            $days++;
        }
    }   

    return (int)$days;

}

echo numWeekDays( $start, $end, 'saturday', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for awhile for a simple solution that worked and decided to write my own and came up with this

```
        $start = date('Y-m-d');
        $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start.' +1 year'));
        $current = $start;
        $count = 0;

        while($current != $end){
            if(date('l', strtotime($current)) == 'Saturday'){
                $count++;
            }

            $current = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($current.' +1 day'));
        };

        echo $count;
```