# How to get saturday and sunday between two date in java

Tags: java, android

```
StartDate:  2016-05-8 20:16:00;
EndDate:    2016-05-30 20:16:00;


     public int saturdaysundaycount(Date d1, Date d2) {
                Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                c1.setTime(d1);

                Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                c2.setTime(d2);

                int sundays = 0;
                int saturday = 0;

                while (c1.after(c2)) {
                    if (c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY || c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
                        sundays++;
                    saturday++;
                    c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }
                System.out.println(sundays);

                return saturday + sundays;
            }
```

In this function I am trying to get total count of Saturdays and Sundays between two dates. But when I pass the date I get zero as a result. Please point out the mistake and suggest corrections.

Comment: Similar kind of question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600034/calculate-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-java) . change the logic instead

Comment: i have tried dear i am unable to do that its always return 0

Comment: if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY && startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)    i have applied this logic

Comment: Why are you doing this `c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);` two times?

Comment: c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);

Comment: you can use joda time for easier implementation :D 
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not advisable to write full program but since you put effort, here is what seems to be working on my system and returning a value of `7`.

```
public class CountWeekends {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        int count = 0;
        try {
            Date d1 = formatter.parse("2016-05-8 20:16:00");
            Date d2 = formatter.parse("2016-05-30 20:16:00");
            count = saturdaysundaycount(d1,d2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Count of Sats & Sundays = "+count);
    }

    public static int saturdaysundaycount(Date d1, Date d2) {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(d1);

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(d2);

        int sundays = 0;
        int saturday = 0;

        while (! c1.after(c2)) {
            if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY ){
                saturday++; 
            }
            if(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY){
                sundays++;
            }

            c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        System.out.println("Saturday Count = "+saturday);
        System.out.println("Sunday Count = "+sundays);
        return saturday + sundays;
    }
```

> Logic: You need to keep increment `start date` by one day till it
>   surpasses `end date` and keep checking `day` on `start date`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `while`, with this piece of code is working fine for me.

Check the `endDate` and `startDate` because I guess that you are sending it in the wrong order.

```
while (endDate.after(startDate)) {
  if (endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY ){
    sundays++;
  }else if (endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY){
    saturday++;
  }

  endDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
}
```

Comment: Error is coming in get MEthod

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getNumberofSundays(String d1,String d2) throws Exception{ //object in Date form
    Date date1=getDate(d1);
    Date date2=getDate(d2);

    Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(date1);
    Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(date2);
    int sundays=0;
    while(c1.after(c2)){
        if(c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SUNDAY){
            sundays++;
            c2.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("number of days between 2 dates"+sundays);

    return sundays;
}
```

Comment: we have to add Saturday also not only Sunday

Comment: dude same way count Saturday

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/UZxjmwmfePGtQCxPtevyLu  look this is it but its not working

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment "404 Not Found"

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not loop through the days. Please try the following code. In the while loop it loops through all the days between the given fist date and last date. It does this by adding a day to c1 in every iteration until c1 is after c2. This gives number of Saturdays and Sundays between given dates including those two days.

```
public static int saturdaysundaycount(Date d1, Date d2) {
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(d2);

    int sundays = 0;
    int saturdays = 0;

    while (!c1.after(c2)) {
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-E");
        String formatted = format1.format(c1.getTime());
        System.out.println("Current Date C1 : " + formatted);

        if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            sundays++;
        } else if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            saturdays++;
        }
        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    System.out.println("Sundays : " + sundays);
    System.out.println("Saturdays : " + saturdays);

    return saturdays + sundays;
}
```