# Java Calendar: I want to remove specific Day of week from calendar

Tags: java, date-range, weekday, java-calendar

More details I want to get rid of specific days of the week.

I mean like: `{Sat(1), Sun(2), Mon(3) , Tues(4) , Wed (5),Thurs(6) ,Fri(7)}`.

Remove Week Days: `{Sat(1), Sun(2), Mon(3) , Tues(4) , Wed (5)}`.

So I can get the Count of days without the excluded days from the specific start date to the date of now.

**Hint**: I must Use the Java Calendar

The problem is specifying the day dynamically

Comment: Your question is kind of hard to understand. You want to count the number of Thursdays + Fridays between to dates?

Comment: I want to get the count of days from specific from start date to end date excluding this two days

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate number of weekdays between two dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600034/calculate-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: if your purpose is just counting number of days between 2 dates and without counting some specific days in week, I think this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600034/calculate-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: Why do you have to use `Calendar`? Can't you use `LocalDate` ?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude those 2 days? What are the conditions for removing them?

Comment: I want to exclude a specific number of days as i want to get the number of assigned days  and non assigned days

Comment: So you have a user that says "I don't like mondays, they dont count" (for whatever reason). And the user wants to know how many days are between a certain range, without those mondays? I.e.: "From 03/04/2017 to 05/07/2017 ... how many days are there without mondays"? Is this assumption correct?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use LocalDate and stream you can apply a functional approach.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 28);

List<DayOfWeek> includedDays = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);

long daysCount = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
        .filter(d -> includedDays.contains(d.getDayOfWeek()))
        .count();
```

If you insist on calendar just use:

```
GregorianCalendar calendarStart = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 2, 1);
GregorianCalendar calendarEnd = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 2, 28);

List<Integer> includedDays = Arrays.asList(GregorianCalendar.THURSDAY, GregorianCalendar.FRIDAY);
long count = 0;
while(!calendarStart.equals(calendarEnd)) {
    if(includedDays.contains(calendarStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
        count ++;
    }
    calendarStart.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Comment: the days will be added dynamically not static days

Comment: Can't you just create dynamic list for `includedDays`?

Comment: its included dynamically from the user from a front end interface

Comment: Setting the day dynamically is the problem

Comment: Alright, so you have to dynamically transform it to list. How do you expect me to give you more precise answer if you didn't show how data comes in from frontend?

Comment: it comes as Array of ints

Comment: as the the calendar days start from 1 and end to 7

Comment: This list is just example assuming you would like to include Thursday and Friday. `GregorianCalendar.THURSDAY` is constant from class `GregorianCalendar` with value `5` and `GregorianCalendar.FRIDAY` is `6`. List `includedDays` is already list of ints, so you will have just to use your data instead of this hardcoded example.

Comment: @Eng.Gabr This would be **a lot** easier if you would provide some example code. Apart from that i really don't see what the problem is in converting an array of ints to a list of Integers.

Comment: And this is what I canot solve conditioning either the number is equal to `Calendar.THURSDAY` equals to 5 or not to push the value of these days to the calendar

Comment: `Calendar.THURSDAY` is just constant with value 5. Line of code where list is created, could be written as:
`Arrays.asList(new int[]{5, 6});` Instead of hardcoded `new int[]{5,6};` just use your data from frontend.

Comment: @RandallFlagg Thank you very much

Comment: I just recognized that you are mentioning List of integers