# Calculate number of specific day between two dates in php

Tags: php, date, diff

I want to find the total number of specific days between two dates. I need a proper solution for future usage, I want to use any start date and end date in the future.

My Code

```
$start_date       = new DateTime('2020/10/01');
$end_date         = new DateTime('2020/10/31'); 
$days = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
$diff = $start_date->diff($end_date, true)->days;
foreach ($days as $key => $value) {
   $number_of_days = intval($diff / 7) + ($start_date->format('N') + $diff % 7 >= $key+1);
   $result[$value] = $number_of_days;
}
```

result

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => 5
    [Tuesday] => 5
    [Wednesday] => 5
    [Thursday] => 5
    [Friday] => 5
    [Saturday] => 5
    [Sunday] => 5
)
```

Expecting Result

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => 4
    [Tuesday] => 4
    [Wednesday] => 4
    [Thursday] => 5
    [Friday] => 5
    [Saturday] => 5
    [Sunday] => 4
)
```

Comment: _“Expecting Result”_ - why? November 2020 has 5 Mondays and Sundays, and all other days occur _four_ times.

Comment: And what's your question? Is there anything not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: @04FS someone edited my question, he changed the month, now please check the date

Comment: _Almost exact_ duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886166/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa There is some difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check next solution:

```
<?php
// create DateTime objects for date start & date end
$start_date       = new DateTime('2020/11/01');
$end_date         = new DateTime('2020/11/31'); 

// initialize counter array fro each day of week
$res = array(
    'Monday'   => 0,
    'Tuesday'  => 0,
    'Wednesday'=> 0,
    'Thursday' => 0,
    'Friday'   => 0,
    'Saturday' => 0,
    'Sunday'   => 0
);

// iterate dates between $start_date & $end_date
// if $end_date should not be included '<=' should be changed to '<'
while ($start_date <= $end_date) {
    $week_day = $start_date->format('l'); // get weekday for each date in interval
    $res[$week_day]++;                    // increase weekday counter
    $start_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // iterate next day
}

print_r($res);
```

Here live code [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=69e87b5d24f8c08458bb3a19e95d23b9&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: If you can add the explanation for educational purpose, it maybe helps a lot of people

Comment: I added explanation comments in code. Will try to explain better

Answer (score -2):

First of all: The week starts with Sunday.

```
    $weekDays = ['Sunday', ...];
```

Then do not do something in a loop that is not dependend on the loop value:

```
$numberOfDays = intval($diff / 7);
foreach ($weekDays as $weekDay) {
    $result[$weekDay] = $numberOfDays;
}
for ($weekDay = $startDate->format('N'), $endWeekDay = $endDate->format('N'); $weekDay != $endWeekday; $weekDay = ($weekDay + 1) % 7){
    $result[$weekday]++;
}
```

Answer might change a bit depending on whether you want to include the start and end date.

Comment: "The week starts with Sunday" - what do you mean by that? According to ISO 8601, monday is the first day of the week, which is consensus in most western countries