# PHP Get number of Sat&Sun for each month between two dates

Tags: php, datetime

### What I am Trying

I am able to get the number of sat&sun between two dates. What I want is to get the number of sat&sun for each month between those dates.

Suppose start_date is 4-Jul-2015 and end_date is 30-Aug-2015. Then there is 8 sat&sun in Jul and 10 in Aug.

From what I did I'm getting 18. But I need to get 8 and 10. How can I get this
?

### Code

```
$countSat = 0;
$countSun = 0;
$start = new DateTime($_POST['start']);
$end   = new DateTime($_POST['end']);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt)
 {
  if ($dt->format('N') == 7)
  {
    $countSun++;
  }
  if ($dt->format('N') == 6)
  {
    $countSat++;
  }
}
$count = $countSat + $countSun;
```

Comment: How can there be 8 or 10 weekends in a month ?!

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be sat&sun, typo

Comment: Use an array, where the key is the month. So you will do `$countSun[$month]++;`

Comment: Figure out the months in-between those dates; figure out how many days are in each month and the start weekday; do a bit of math involving the number 7.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958693/calculating-the-number-of-saturdays-and-sundays possible duplicate

Comment: @deceze yeah, some Maths with modulo may save loops :)

Answer (score 1):

try this option:

```
$countSat = 0;
$countSun = 0;
$i = 0;
$start = new DateTime($_POST['start']);
$month = $start->format('n');
$end   = new DateTime($_POST['end']);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt)
{
  if($month != $dt->format('n'))
  {
    $results[$i]=$countSun+$countSat;
    $i++;
    $countSun=0;
    $countSat=0;
  }

  if ($dt->format('N') == 7)
  {
   $countSun++;
  }
  if ($dt->format('N') == 6)
  {
   $countSat++;
  }
  $month = $dt->format('n');
}
```

Comment: could you explain a bit. didnt get it. How will I get the value?

Comment: each array element indicates the number of Saturday and Sunday of each month: 
`for(int $j = 0; $j<$result.length;$j++){
  echo "on", $j+1 ," - month of period: ", $result[j] ," sun&sat"; 
}`

Comment: you need to specify the number of the month? For example: a 7-month 8 pieces Saturday + Sunday, an 8-month 10 pieces Saturday + Sunday?

Comment: Not getting. The problem is, Aug 30 is sun so if end date is 29 then there will be only 9 in Aug.