# Incrementing days if day is a workday

Tags: php

I need your help again.
This should be a function for php. I've got two dates. One is set by myDate and the other one is the date of today. I want to find out the number of days left to myDate, but saturday and sundy should be excluded. The result for this function would be 7...
How can I make it work?

```
<?php
myDate = "29.07.2010 "
```

DaysTillmyDate = 0
iterate day to myDate {
 if (date/day is a weekday(Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday, Friday))
   increment DaysTillmyDate by 1
}
?>

A hint or any help would be much appreciated.
Faili

Comment: use this - duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick iteration:

```
$days = 0;
for($i = time(); $i < (strtotime('29.07.2010') + 86400); $i=$i+86400)
{
    $weekday = date('w', $i);
    if($weekday > 0 &&  $weekday < 6)
    {
       $days++; 
    }
}

echo $days;
```

Comment: That was quick. Thanks to all.

Comment: You are welcome. I found that piece of code once and I saved it into my library. Anyway, I will never use it, since there are better ways to do it. Just take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days for a much better approach.

Comment: hmm, would that have failed on December 31st, 2008. 23:59:60? (Yes, it existed). That time + 86400 would have been January 2nd. An edge case if I ever saw one, nonetheless...

Comment: @Wrikken - interesting. Anyway, your edge case is somehow strange and the probability to replicate is extremely rare.

Answer (score 0):

`date('N', $theDate)` gives you the day of the week (6 for Saturday and 7 for Sunday). From there, you can easily implement a function that does only counts workdays. On the other hand, this does not detect holidays.

Comment: You're right. I always assume dates to be in timestamp format ;) the conversion from YYYY/MM/DD can be made with strtotime()