# Calculating next business day

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I calculate Next Business Day given a Zend_Date and a cutoff time of 5pm? Business days are M-F (weekdays).

Example:
Fri 4 pm should return same date
Sat anytime should return next Mon
Tue 8 pm should return Wed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Next business day of given date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532002/next-business-day-of-given-date-in-php)

Comment: I know how I'd do it in PHP with adding days to time() but there has to be a better way

Comment: @gandalf007 Why must there? What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: @Blowski yes I just saw that, didn't know how to translate that from/to Zend_Date

Comment: Will you need to exclude holidays?

Comment: @gandalf007 Welcome to StackOverflow. If you can show us the specific problem that you're having, we'll help you to fix it. At the moment, your question reads a little bit like "please write the following code for me". There's no context of why you need to do this, what you've already tried, and why the other related questions do not solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has been asked before, [Next business day of given date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5532002/961455), but here it is using Zend_Date:

```
$now = new Zend_Date();
if (($now->get(Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_DIGIT) % 6 == 0)
 || ($now->isLater('17:00:00', Zend_Date::TIMES))
) { 
    $now->set(
        strtotime('+1 weekday', $now->toString(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP)),
        Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP
    );
}   
echo $now->toString(Zend_Date::W3C);
```