# How do I get the next day of the week?

Tags: php, date

Like if today is Thursday, then I want to display Friday using php date() function.
For example, the below code will show the current month but the next day of the month. It worked. `<?php echo date("M "), date("d")+1 ?>`

So I was trying through this one `<?php echo date("l")+1, date("d")+1 ?>` and it fooled me :(.

Comment: Recommending searching before posting. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883571/get-next-and-previous-day-with-php
Generalized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532002/next-business-day-of-given-date-in-php

Comment: Actually that question isn't as clear as mine, I hope this question far better than that to understand for beginners. You see my question was so simple and clear hence I got neat & clean answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expression gives you the next day:

```
date('l', time()+3600*24)
```

Comment: While unlikely, this could cause problems with leap seconds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: It's easy and simple. I wanted this type of solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Also, an `l` will produce a full textual representation of the day of the week (e.g. Friday) when using [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Something like the following should do what you want:

```
date('l', strtotime('+1 day'))
```