# Calculate number of working days in a month

Tags: php, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get number of weekdays in a given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396507/get-number-of-weekdays-in-a-given-month)

How to calculate working days of any month? `cal_days_in_month` returns simply the total number of days in a month. My task is to calculate number of days in month except Saturdays and Sundays or Sundays alone. Any method to find this?

Comment: @keune: Saturdays or Sundays is just a example. I may need to calculate without Monday and Thursday for some months, Wednesday and Thursday for some months.

Comment: @SuryaS The accepted answer in the question mentioned above can do that for you too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function countDays($year, $month, $ignore) {
    $count = 0;
    $counter = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    while (date("n", $counter) == $month) {
        if (in_array(date("w", $counter), $ignore) == false) {
            $count++;
        }
        $counter = strtotime("+1 day", $counter);
    }
    return $count;
}
echo countDays(2013, 1, array(0, 6)); // 23
```

The [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is used in this example. Note about ignore parameter: 0 is sunday, ..., 6 is saturday.

Answer (score 13):

copying second answer from : [Get number of weekdays in a given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396507/get-number-of-weekdays-in-a-given-month)

> You don't need to count every day in the month. You already know the
>   first 28 days contain 20 weekdays no matter what. All you have to do
>   is determine the last few days. Change the start value to 29. Then add
>   20 weekdays to your return value.

```
function get_weekdays($m,$y) {
$lastday = date("t",mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y));
$weekdays=0;
for($d=29;$d<=$lastday;$d++) {
    $wd = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y));
    if($wd > 0 && $wd < 6) $weekdays++;
    }
return $weekdays+20;
}
```

This should solve your problem and is an efficient solution indeed.

Answer (score 4):

A simple (not so elegant) answer would simply be to create a time stamp of the first day in the month, use date() to get the physical name of the month, then either switch or if to determine if it's a weekday or not.

```
$myTime = strtotime("1/1/2013");  // Use whatever date format you want
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1, 2013); // 31
$workDays = 0;

while($daysInMonth > 0)
{
    $day = date("D", $myTime); // Sun - Sat
    if($day != "Sun" && $day != "Sat")
        $workDays++;

    $daysInMonth--;
    $myTime += 86400; // 86,400 seconds = 24 hrs.
}

echo "There are $workDays work days this month!";
```

**Output**

```
There are 23 work days this month!
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I would probably go `$myTime=strtotime('+1 day', $myTime);` instead of just adding 86,400 seconds, because I've noticed that adding the number of seconds in a day doesn't always generate consistent results for some reason.

Comment: I Like this method and it works well! +1

Answer (score 1):

Just do a Google search, man.

For posterity, your algorithm:

- Get the number of days in the month using date().
- Starting from day (1), use mktime/gmmktime to create an epoch timestamp, and then use 
  date() to determine what day of the week it represents.
- Repeat, until you've found the first working day (a Monday). Let this be "i".
- Let the current tally be "t", whose initial value is (0).
- Let j = i. Where j is less then (i + 5) -and- less then the maximum number of days in the
  month, increment t. Increment by (2) (to skip the weekend days) and repeat from the
  beginning of this line until "i" has exceeded the maximum number of days in the month.
- Apply success and happiness, and repeat from beginning until total number of working days
  is (0).

Answer (score 0):

```
function countDays($y, $m, $ignore = false) 
{
    $result = 0;
    $loop = strtotime("$y-$m-01");
    do if(!$ignore or !in_array(strftime("%u",$loop),$ignore))
        $result++;
    while(strftime("%m",$loop = strtotime("+1 day",$loop))==$m);
    return $result;
}
echo countDays(2013,1,array(6,7));//23
echo countDays(2013,2);//28
```