# Remove weekends from date range

Tags: php

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848503/609630) to help me but need to work it into my question.

I want to count the days between two dates but then remove the weekends. How can I combine the following two answers?

Date 1 is 06.10.2017 and date 2 is 09.10.2017.

```
$date1 = new DateTime(get_sub_field('start_date'));
$date2 = new DateTime(get_sub_field('end_date'));

$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
echo $diff;
```

That gives 3 days. I want it to show 1 as there's a weekend in there. So I need to combine it with the following:

This next answer removes all weekends:

```
function countDays($year, $month, $ignore) {
    $count = 0;
    $counter = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    while (date("n", $counter) == $month) {
        if (in_array(date("w", $counter), $ignore) == false) {
            $count++;
        }
        $counter = strtotime("+1 day", $counter);
    }
    return $count;
}
echo countDays(2017, 10, array(0, 6)); // 22
```

Giving 22 business days in Oct.

**How can I combine the two answers to show me a count of days between two dates but removing weekends?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365461/day-difference-without-weekends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP date and time classes are very powerful.

I'd use `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod`.

```
$start = new DateTime('2017-10-06');
$end   = new DateTime('2017-10-09');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$businessDays = 0;
foreach ($period as $day) {
    // $day is not saturday nor sunday
    if (! in_array($day->format('w'), [0, 6])) {
        $businessDays++;
    }
}

echo $businessDays; // prints 1
```

Comment: damnit - ninja'd ;)

Comment: @DanFromGermany That's a great succinct answer, thanks. Way better than anything I've seen out there.

Comment: Removed my answer since it was basically identical (almost down the the variable names scarily) and therefore superfluous ;)

Comment: @CD001 yours had a little improvement, it didn't create an array on each iteration, just once.