# Displaying the day name of a month dynamically - PHP

Tags: php

I am looping the days of the current month and I want to display weekdays of the current month as well but i dont know.

```
//showing the days number of the current month
$currentDays = date('d');
for($i=1;$i<=$currentDays;$i++)
{
  //print the day number
  echo $i.'\n';
}
```

Comment: please elaborate and show us the code in question

Comment: What is the object/data-type that you are iterating through?

Comment: I want to display the days name after displaying days number - Uchiha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the timestamp of that specific day and then with that get the weekday name.

```
$days = date( 'd' );
$month = date( 'n' );

for ( $day = 1; $day <= $days; $day++ )
    echo $day, ' is ', date( 'l', strtotime( $month . '/' . $day ) ), '\n';
```

To get a different weekday name for translations whatsoever, you must build your own array and get it through from there by changing the lowercase L to lowercase W, which will return you a weekday integer.

```
$weekdays = array( "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" );
$days = date( 'd' );
$month = date( 'n' );

for ( $day = 1; $day <= $days; $day++ )
    echo $day, ' is ', $weekdays[ date( 'w', strtotime( $month . '/' . $day ) ) ], '\n';
```

Keep in mind that you are using lowercase D in your days-variable, which means it will only count the days until today. You can use lowercase T to loop through all days of the specified month.

The alternative is to use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399169/3264799) related to this question.

In addition, instead of defining weekday names by yourself, you could simply [set the locale](http://php.net/setlocale) setting to your choosing and [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) the weekday name (%A).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
$current_month = date("M");
$first_day_this_month = date('01');
$last_day_this_month  = date('t');
$st_result = '';
for($i=$first_day_this_month; $i<=$last_day_this_month; $i++ ){
    $day = '';
 $day = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, $i, 2015));
    if($day == 'Saturday' || $day == 'Sunday'){continue;}
 else{$st_result = $st_result .','.$i;}
}
echo $st_result ;
?>
```

Comment: This answer does not seem to work, and honestly speaking this code is doing way too many unnecessary things to get to the end result.