# Count The Number of Sundays Till Today for the current Year and current month?

Tags: php

How can I calculate the number of Sundays that have already passed from the current `YEAR` till today. I would also like to calculate the number of Sundays that have already passed from the current `MONTH` till today.

eg

```
today is 14 April 2012 I should get 2 for the Number of Sundays
that are passed from the current month.
```

Can anyone give me a hint or a tutorial how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days. You can find everything you need there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well i guess it is simple enough using the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
//will give you the amount of sundays from the begining of the year
$daysTotal = ceil((date("z") - date("w")) / 7); 
//will give you the amount of sundays from the begining of the month
$daysTotal = ceil((date("j") - date("w")) / 7);
```

I didn't test it, you might want to check if the round() function works right in this situation but the point is passed i think

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Date('W') might help you. Check php manual for the format - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php .

Do not forget according to manual - ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday.
So this week will be counted even if this not Sunday yet. So in that case reduce the number by 1.

```
function get_sunday_since_year_start($today=null)
{
  if($today==null) $today = time();

  if(date('D',$today)=='Sun')
    return Date('W',$today);
  else
    return Date('W',$today)-1;
}

function get_sunday_since_month_start()
{
   return get_sunday_since_year_start()-get_sunday_since_year_start(strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00')));
}
```