# How do I get the number of days between two dates excluding the weekend

Tags: php

This is what i tried:

```
$date1 = date_create('2015-06-03');
$date2 = date_create('2015-06-11');
$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
echo $diff;
```

This returns me the number: 8 . I want to get the number of days between two dates, excluding Saturdays and Sundays and including the start date and end date. How can I do that? So in my case the result should be 7.

Comment: Check out this one, seems to be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365461/day-difference-without-weekends

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365461/day-difference-without-weekends

Comment: Thx but, what is P1D  ?

Comment: As you can read here: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php
`P` should be the first letter of the parameter and `1D` means "1 days".