# Exclude Datetime Weekend (Saturday and Sunday) from Difference (Interval) between two Datetime

Tags: php, sql, datetime, difference

I have this code:

```
<?php
include_once '../php/connect.php';

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){    
  echo '<tr><td colspan="6">No data!</td></tr>';
}
else 
{
  $no = 1; 
  $i=0;
  while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
  $datetime1 = new DateTime();
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($data['lup']);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  $elapsed = $interval->format('%a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');

  $arraysum[$i] = $elapsed;

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$data['lup'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$elapsed.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';

  $no++;    
  $i++;
}
  echo array_sum($arraysum);
?>
```

How to exclude weekend days (Saturday and Sunday) then that day not count in difference/interval?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Day difference without weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365461/day-difference-without-weekends)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365461/day-difference-without-weekends

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of [tag:php-5.5]. So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189