# Comparison between two dates

Tags: php

I have done this function so that I have as a result the working days without counting the weekend between two dates, in the database I have the date fields as DATATIME, but at the time of executing I get this error:

A non well formed numeric value encountered

The function is as follows:

```
function diashabiles ($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin) {

    list ($year, $month, $day) = explode ("/", $fecha_inicio);
    $ini = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
    list ($yearf, $mesf, $diaf) = explode ("/", $fecha_fin);
    $fin = mktime (0, 0, 0, $mesf, $diaf, $yearf);
    $newArray = array ();
    $r = 1; $i = 0; $dia2 = 0;

    while ($ini! = $fin) {
    $ini = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, $day + $r, $year);
    $newArray [$i] = $ini;
    $r++; $i++;
    }


    for ($i = 0; $i <count($newArray); $i++) {
    $day = $newArray [$i];
    $date = getdate($day);
    if ($date["wday"] == 0 or $date["wday"] == 6) {
    $dia2++;
    }
    }

    $rlt = count($newArray) - $dia2;
    return $rlt;

}
```

Thank You!!

Comment: Do you really have a space after each `$` in the code?

Comment: No. That's what the editor did, right now I'm modifying it.

Comment: What is the actual error message you get? I am guessing there is a line-number, or some additional detail?

Comment: The code is correct, can you help me?

Comment: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Here is the error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: `$fin` is undefined in the `while` loop.

Comment: The $fin is already changed and I still get that error. The function tells me well the days but I get that error too

Comment: I think the error is in putting the date field as DATATIME in the database but not because it gives an error

Comment: This function works with a database but I think it's because of the DATATIME field but I can not find the solution

Comment: My question about the error was to ascertain where the error was occurring, because that is probably related to the data (which I have no knowledge of).

Comment: I had the date fields in the database as DATE, but when I changed them to DATETIME I got the error

Comment: If you managed to solve your issue, based on an answer, then you should mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script works well if you replace

while ($ini != $fin)

**with this**

while ($ini <= $fin).

But i still suggest you to check this link [Use DateTime, DateInterval and DatePeriod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365635/1939258)

Comment: It is true that your change would prevent infinite looping, but the OP isn't even getting to that part of the code.

Comment: diashabiles('2018/02/16', '2018/02/19');
Output is 2 days. 

Share your dates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this code:

```
list ($year, $month, $day) = explode ("/", $fecha_inicio);
$ini = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
list ($yearf, $mesf, $diaf) = explode ("/", $fecha_fin);
$fin = mktime (0, 0, 0, $mesf, $diaf, $yearf);
```

You stated that initially, the data stored was in DATE format, which means that what was coming out of the database was simply a year, month and a day. Then, you changed the data type to be DATETIME, which obviously changes what is stored in the database, and obviously changes what is retrieved.

In short, your explode function will leave you with the following:

`$year =` whatever year is in the database. Can be numeric.
`$month =` whatever month is in the database. Can be numeric.
`$day =` the rest, which will include day, hour, minute, second. Definitely not numeric.

When you use the above information (with the day being a string rather than a number) then `mktime()` fails.

Comment: So $day do I have to declare it as whole or as? I do not understand

Comment: The point is that what comes out of the database probably looks like: 
`2018/01/27 13:05:21`. Now, when you `explode()` this with the `/` separator, you get: `2018`, `01`, and `27 13:05:21`. I am partly guessing, but this is the likely case. So, you need to extract the `27` from the last value... maybe `explode()` it again with the separator as the space character: " "?