# PHP - total number of days is not an integer

Tags: php, date, datetime

The accepted answer in this question: [Calculate business days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days) is buggy. Just check

```
echo getWorkingDays("2012-01-01","2012-05-01",$holidays);
```

The problem is with this fragment:

```
$days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;
```

So the minimal not working example is:

Why this expression:

```
($endDate - $startDate) / (60*60*24);
```

Is not an integer for:

```
 $startDate = strtotime("2012-01-01");
 $endDate = strtotime("2012-05-01");
```

Comment: why don't you ask that in the comments of the question you mentioned? Maybe it can help others landing there too ...

Comment: First because no one will look at it.
Secondly because the problem is not with idea of this function but elsewhere.

Comment: What is the result of the expression?  What timezone are you working in?

Comment: Presumably because the clocks change between those dates for the timezone your using.  But yeah, this really should be asked in the comments of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've crossed a DST threshold. Whenever you do so your duration will be (usually) one hour shorter or longer. If you wish to avoid this then work exclusively with UTC.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio says, it's because of passing the start (last Sunday of March) or end (last Sunday od October) of Daylight Saving Time... so you end up losing/gaining an hour and thus messing up the calculation.

All I added was round() to the equation and it deals with the situation perfectly :)

```
$days = round( (strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 86400 + 1);
```