# PHP Class to Calculate Business Days

Tags: php, api, days

So I've been googling around the web trying to find some sort of PHP API that nicely handles the calculation of business days.  I found a number of [answers and code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days/13633743#13633743) on stackoverflow which were helpful, but the code I found that handled adding business days to a given date lacked certain features I need (e.g. handling holidays that fall on a weekend), and it was difficult to customize based on a given application's needs.

So I finally decided to bite the bullet and write my own solution.  The class I've produced incorporates code that I found on stackoverflow ([James Pasta++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days/13633743#13633743)) as well as logic used in a similar (and simpler) Java class that I wrote last year.  I'm posting it here Q/A style in case anyone else encounters the same frustrations that I've had with this concept, and finds it a useful solution.

There are two basic problems that I tackled - 1) adding business days to a provided date, and 2) counting the business days between two dates.  My primary concerns in solving these issues were ease of use and extensibility; there are a number of places that were written less than efficiently; if it becomes an issue I can certainly refactor parts of the code, but at least for my purposes, I won't be calculating thousands of business days into the future :-)

Sample code and a link to the source can be found in the answer below.  Feedback and improvements are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[The Code](https://snipt.net/raw/01aff150df5edcc770c5f2c0d6e49a87/?nice)

The basic concept of this library is that a date is wrapped with a BusinessDay object; it can then be compare()d with other dates, or it can have business days add()ed or subtract()ed.  All dates provided to the library can be one of the following four types: a date string accepted by strtotime(), a UNIX timestamp, another BusinessDay object or null (represents the current time).

BusinessDay objects can be instantiated via a new statement, or by a function called wrapBusinessDay().  Using the latter option allows method chaining upon instantiation, which can help keep code succinct.  See the sample code below.

Sample Code:

```
// add a business day to today
$ship_date = wrapBusinessDay(time())->add(1);

// find # of business days until required date
$required_date = '6/24/2013';
$difference = $ship_date->difference($required_date);

// panic?!
if ($difference < 10) {
    echo "Uh-oh, we'll need expedited shipping!\n";
} else {
    echo "Whew!  we're safe.\n";
}

// specify custom holidays
$arr_matey = wrapBusinessDay('2013-09-18', array(
    '2013-09-19'
))->add(1);

// specify custom formats
echo $arr_matey . "\n";                      // prints '2013-09-20 00:00:00'
echo $arr_matey->dateFormat('m~d~Y') . "\n"; // prints '09~20~2013'
```

There's more to the library, but that's the gist of it.  Hope this'll save somebody else some time!
~ Nate

Comment: Very good.. but this solution does not account for holidays on weekends that are observed on weekdays...FYI