# PHP Date range array for the last 40 sundays

Tags: php, arrays, date

Is there a way to put the last 40 sundays into an array with php? I don't get it right now.

tried the following

```
$week_array = array();
$last_s = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last sunday'));
array_push($week_array, $last_s);       
for ($i = 0; $i <= 40; $i++ ) {
  $last_s = $last_s - 7;
  array_push($week_array, $last_s);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Show us what you've tried first and then we'll help you out.

Comment: What have you tried? Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking for code ***must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved***. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_

Comment: Related question is here already : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 40 ; $i++){
   $week = 3600*24*7; 
   $dates[] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last Sunday")))-$week*$i) ;

}
print_r($dates);
?>
```

**[see example](http://codepad.org/MhfhYhcA)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$sundays = array();
$now = new DateTime();
if ($now->format('l') === 'Sunday') {
    $sundays[] = $now->format("Y-m-d");
}
$dt = new DateTime('last sunday');
while (count($sundays) < 40) {
    $sundays[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $dt->modify('-1 week');
}
print_r($sundays);
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LUqzce)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Use this code

```
$sundays = array();

// $prev is auxillary variable which holds the time 
// from which we are searching the next last Sunday
$prev = time();

for($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++)
{
  $prev = strtotime('last Sunday', $prev);  // 
  $sundays[] = $prev;  
}
```

Comment: What if today is a sunday?

Comment: @JohnConde You may easily initialize `$prev` to next Sunday.