# Get date before specified workdays

Tags: php, date

I want to subtract `$date` with `$interval`, please note that `$interval` is number of workdays. Here are some examples (format: yyyy-mm-dd)

- `$date` = 2013-10-07, `$interval` = 5, `$result` = 2013-09-30
- `$date` = 2013-10-07, `$interval` = 1, `$result` = 2013-10-04

My code so far

```
$div = floor($interval / 5);
$mod = $interval % 5;
$workdays = $div * 7 + $mod;
$result = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . "-$workdays days"));
```

- `$date` = 2013-10-07, `$interval` = 5, `$result` = 2013-09-30 => true
- `$date` = 2013-10-07, `$interval` = 1, `$result` = 2013-10-06 => **false**

Please give me direction to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: if you just want to skip saturdays and sundays then you can build a simple function that checks the date. But if you want to take into account also holidays then it's more complicated. Look at this discussion if it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your workdays as *MON-FRI* then all you need to do is use the `weekdays` keyword of `strtotime`. Resulting in something like `strtotime("-7 weekdays")`
 which will exclude saturdays and sundays.

Or following your code:

```
$workdays = 5;
$result = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . "-$workdays weekdays"));
```

**Issues with this answer**

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63521

Comment: interesting... but if I try the first example it give me `2013-09-28`

Comment: @chumkiu make sure that you're taking into account the server time, maybe it's not what you are assuming it is?

Comment: please try `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-10-07 -5 weekdays"));` I got 2013-09-28. I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

#### Use example:

```
var_dump( subtractWorkDays('2013-10-07', 5) ); # 2013-09-30
var_dump( subtractWorkDays('2013-10-07', 1) ); # 2013-10-04
```

#### Function:

```
function subtractWorkDays($date, $days) {
    return date_create($date)->modify("-$days weekdays")->format('Y-m-d');
}
```