# how to auto run a php script and delete a record from database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I Could use some help, i want to auto run a script that deletes a record from my db after 48 working hours (excluding weekends) - some kind of timer if you will.

Tried using phpmyadmin triggers but there're not doing precisely what i want.

Additionally: On my db i've got a listed_date column - which stores the date and time the record was added and i also have a expiry_date column which stores a future date (when the record should expire/be deleted)

Any thoughts??

Comment: thanks, ill give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a `PHP` script, create a `query` in PHP:

`//connect to mysql database, then run a query with the following logic`

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `expiry_date` <= NOW();
```

This script oculd be set up in `crontab` to run every n mins:

```
0 * * * * cd /script/directory; php script.php; > /dev/null
```

This will run on the hour, every hour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The cronjob execution now works, however the logic on the sql is somehow confusing: i just want to delete records that are 48 hours old (and older) excluding weekends hours (i've bypassed the weeeknd part by executing the script during weekdays only)

Comment: Glad to help. Your `expiry_date` column holds a datetime equivalent to the time the entry was added, plus 48 hours. `now()` function in `MySQL` returns the current datetime. In the query you are removing all entries that have an `expiry_date` value less than or equal to the current datetime.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

You could achieve the same effect by comparing your `listed_date` column with `NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR`, thus removing entries dated earlier than 48 hours ago. Is this clear?

Comment: This helped alot! Thanks again :-) Managing to do what i wanted by combining your sugetions with the solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days