# Showing a certain date without calculating the weekend days

Tags: php, date

In my application i want to show a certain date without calculate the weekend days.

So i have date when promotion start: `2016-11-03`. promotion lasts for `45` days.

`$value['invesdate'] // 2016-11-03`

`$businessdays= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['invesdate'] . ' +45 day'));`

Start of promotion `2016-11-03` plus (+) `45` days = `2016-12-15`

This is wrong date becouse i calculate and weekend days. 
The corrct date is `2016-01-05`

How do I remove the calculation weekend days ?

Comment: Best answer i have got for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$startDate = '2016-11-03';
$numberofdays = 45;

$d = new DateTime( $startDate );
$t = $d->getTimestamp();

// loop for X days
for($i=0; $i<$numberofdays; $i++){

    // add 1 day to timestamp
    $addDay = 86400;

    // get what day it is next day
    $nextDay = date('w', ($t+$addDay));

    // if it's Saturday or Sunday get $i-1
    if($nextDay == 0 || $nextDay == 6) {
        $i--;
    }

    // modify timestamp, add 1 day
    $t = $t+$addDay;
}

$d->setTimestamp($t);

echo $d->format( 'Y-m-d' ). "\n";
```

**DEMO** http://phpio.net/s/azq

Answer (score -1):

Another shortest way to do this:

```
$businessdays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['invesdate'] . ' +45 weekdays'));
echo $businessdays;
```

There are many predefined references given in PHP documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).