# How do I return a projection date based on a start date, workforce and budgeted hours on working days?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to calculate the return date using a start date, how many hours a team of workers can work a day (16 workforce hours in this case) and how many total budget hours allocated to the project skipping Saturday and Sunday.

Below is a working function to calculate these hours, however, it does not run for return dates using an excessive amount of budgeted hours (5000+)

```
function projectionDate($Date, $Budget_Hours) {
  if (date('l', $Date->format("Y-m-d")) == 'Saturday' 
      || date('l', $Date->format("Y-m-d")) == 'Sunday') {
    return projectionDate($Date->add(new DateInterval('P1D')));
  }

  if ($Budget_Hours <= 16) {
    return $Date->format("Y-m-d");
  } else { 
    return projectionDate($Date->add(new DateInterval('P1D')), $Budget_Hours - 16);
  }
}
```

> echo projectionDate(new DateTime('2017-10-26', '1000') 
>   2017-12-27

Comment: Using recursion is not appropriate in this case. You are using too much memory and have too many recursive calls. Try a different approach like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days . I strongly suggest looking at all the solutions available, especially one that takes holidays into consideration.

Comment: Format specifier `N` gives you 1 for Monday to 7 for Sunday - so skip the weekends by simply checking for `N < 6`. Simply keep the loop going, adding one day to your DateTime object at a time, until you've reached the needed amount of business hours. If you want to take national/bank holidays into account as well, then to keep it simple for a start I'd suggest you go grab the relevant data from some website (copy&paste), and put those dates for the next couple years into an array, in simple `yyyy-mm-dd` form, and then use in_array to check against the same formated current loop date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function projectionDate($Date, $Budget_Hours, $Workforce_Hours = 8, $Holidays = array()){
  $oneDayDateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
  while($Budget_Hours > $Workforce_Hours || in_array($Date->format('Y-m-d'),$Holidays)){
    if($Date->format("N") < 6 && !in_array($Date->format('Y-m-d'), $Holidays)){
      $Budget_Hours -= $Workforce_Hours;
    }
    $Date = $Date->add($oneDayDateInterval);
  }
  return $Date->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

Here's also a lazy way of doing USA Federal Holidays. However each year it will push back the projection date because it only processes this year.

```
function getHolidaysThisYear($Holidays = array()){
  $oneDayDateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
  $MartinLutherKing = new DateTime(date("Y")."-01-15");
  while($MartinLutherKing->format("l") != "Monday"){$MartinLutherKing->add($oneDayDateInterval);}
  $WashingtonBirthday = new DateTime(date("Y")."-02-15");
  while($WashingtonBirthday->format("l") != "Monday"){$WashingtonBirthday->add($oneDayDateInterval);}
  $MemorialDay = new DateTime(date("Y")."-05-25");
  while($MemorialDay->format("l") != "Monday"){$MemorialDay->add($oneDayDateInterval);}
  $LaborDay = new DateTime(date("Y")."-09-01");
  while($LaborDay->format("l") != "Monday"){$LaborDay->add($oneDayDateInterval);}
  $ColombusDay = new DateTime(date("Y")."-10-08");
  while($ColombusDay->format("l") != "Monday"){$ColombusDay->add($oneDayDateInterval);}
  $ThanksGiving = new DateTime(date("Y")."-11-22");
  while($ThanksGiving->format("l") != "Thursday"){$ThanksGiving->add($oneDayDateInterval);}
  $Holidays = array_merge($Holidays,array(date("Y") . "-01-01",date("Y") . "-06-04",date("Y") . "-11-11",date("Y"). "-12-25",$MartinLutherKing->format("Y-m-d"),$WashingtonBirthday->format("Y-m-d"),$MemorialDay->format("Y-m-d"),$LaborDay->format("Y-m-d"),$ColombusDay->format("Y-m-d"),$ThanksGiving->format("Y-m-d")));
  return $Holidays;
 }
```

Comment: `date('l',$Date->format("Y-m-d"))` - that should not even work - `date` expects a unix timestamp as second parameter, not a `yyyy-mm-dd` string value.

Comment: `new DateInterval('P1D')` - that's gone be the same _in value_ any time, so no need to create a _new object_ every time. Initialize `$oneDayDateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');` once before the loop, and then use that inside the `$Date->add` calls.

Comment: And then, you are still doing the same thing - adding a day onto the date - twice, in both the if and else branch. Reverse the logic - if it is _not_ a weekend (`$Date->format('N') < 6`), _then_ subtract 16h from the business hours. _Away_ with the else branch, instead add one day onto date unconditionally, and end of loop body `}` ...

Comment: As for the $Date->Format("Y-m-d") it is strange, in my code it does work however not in a php sandbox online.

Comment: That sounds rather like a weird side effect of I don't know what on your machine (do you have full PHP error reporting enabled?), than something that should actually work. Again, I am pleading for `N`, the number of the day in the week ... can get "anything that is not a weekend" easier than that.

Comment: `date('l',$Date->format("N"))` - no, that still doesn't make much sense ... `N` is between 1 and 7, and interpreted as a unix timestamp, that means between 1 and 7 _seconds_ after 1.1.1970, 0:00:00 ... and formatting that as `l` should pretty much return the _same_ week day every time. `if($Date->format("N") < 6)` is what you want here, plain & simple.

Comment: P.s., carefully consider what you actually want as a result - if you want people to start working _on_ $Date, then I think the logic of what you have now should still be reversed. Now you are first adding a day onto date, and then you check whether it's on a weekend. If $Date was a Friday, and you don't want those to be _ah everyone just stay home today_ "casual", then you want to check for !weekend and subtract from the business hours first, and then move on to checking tomorrow (Saturday) in the next loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I wouldn't have caught that. As for Holidays, would it best be put in as ($Date->Format("N") < 6 && !in_array($Date->format("Y-m-d"),$Holidays)?

Comment: I was already typing something in that regard, but you seem to have been spurred on by my comments already :-) Yes, exactly the way to incorporate that nifty little feature as well, in a simple and easy-to-use way. Might want to do a rough calculation of how far into the future you'd have to go with holiday dates in that array, if 5k business hours or even more are realistic uses case. Depending on that, or for a future endeavors, you could start looking for an API that can return holidays for a specific region, and set up a cron job to regularly fetch those ... have fun :-)

Comment: `$Budget_Hours += -$Workforce_Hours;`- let's make that into `$Budget_Hours -= $Workforce_Hours;` for final _un-knotting of thoughts_, and I'll shut my trap for tonight ;-)

Comment: _"or for a future endeavors"_ - not what I meant to say there ... for future experimentation and improvement, should the fever have caught you, was what I meant.

Comment: Fixed for holidays. If it ended on a holiday, it wasn't working. I didn't put it in the while loop condition because I thought it would use more processing power. Or is it recommended to put in the loop because it won't be checked unless there is not enough workforce hours?